# SQL*Plus script hangs

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I am running a script in sql*plus, it's located in the Desktop and my command is:

```
@C:\users\intel\desktop\script1.sql
```

When I press enter key, the pointer just go to the next line and blink there and then nothing is done. Even I can't write anything. What's the problem??

This is the part of my script:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
(
    ADDRESSID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FLAG CHAR(1),
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Category (
  CategoryId INTEGER   NOT NULL  ,
  CategoryName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(CategoryId)
);
```

Comment: The script is running, probably. Put `set echo on` at the start of the script to have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: It has just printed one table but then same thing, nothing happens.

Comment: Well maybe the statements you're running are just taking a long time to run?

Comment: there are just 12 tables in my script and they have foreign key relations.

Comment: You can't have tables in scripts, you can only have statements. Can't tell what's happening without seeing the script.

Comment: @user1844205, please _edit_ your question with additional information. Don't put it in the comments... We'll need to see the entire thing as we don't know where it's "hanging".

Answer (score 1):

Type `/` and press enter.This will run the command buffer

Comment: There may be errors in your script. Try to create the tables one by one.

Comment: If there are errors then sql plus display them, but nothing happens.

Comment: set echo on
CREATE TABLE CHECK1(
 ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 NAME VARCHAR(50)
);
Is this seems to be Invalid ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have had a pending transaction. Try to commit / rollback your transactions and run your script again.